# Ag-grid: console.log in rowContainerComponent

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I just updated to the latest ag-grid (7.2.0) and now I am getting console.log messages on all of my pages. It says "visible = false" and it apepars to be coming from a rowContrainerComponent.js file.

Is anybody else having this issue and is there a way to opt out of console logs or will we have to change the package until an update is in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release 7.2.1 of ag-grid fixes this

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/commit/20dee241c53eb4491ac73ab5ad1d4b23a27d9e8f#diff-e94ec7fbebcaa6dafa26a6a86ebac842